# When does chmod fail?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod, access-control

Under what circumstances will `chmod` fail?

I looked at the man page but it only specifies usage and doesn't go into details about what circumstances it won't work in.

I'd assume `chmod` will work if:

- you're root
- you own the target file (and are setting a mundane mode bit i.e. not sticky bit, others)

Can users use `chmod` to change permissions on a file they have group access for?  Is it related to read/write access?

Comment: It will fail if the inode can't be modified, eg the filesystem is read only.

Comment: Related: [Can I allow users to chmod a file not owned by them?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75893/50602)

Answer (score 5):

Only the owner of the file, or the root user, may change a file's permissions. The current permissions on the file or on its parent directory are irrelevant¹. This is specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html):

> The application shall ensure that the effective user ID of the process matches the owner of the file or the process has appropriate privileges in order to do this.

On most unices, “appropriate privileges” means running as root. If these conditions are not met, `chmod` usually fails with `EPERM`, though other behaviors such as aborting the program due to a security violation are permitted.

In addition, some unix variants have system-specific ways of authorizing or forbidding `chmod`. For example, Linux has a [capability](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (`CAP_FOWNER`) that allows processes to change a file's permissions and other metadata regardless of its owner.

There are other reasons `chmod` might fail even though the file exists, is accessible and has the appropriate owner. Common ones include a read-only filesystem or a filesystem that does not support permissions such as FAT. Less common ones include system-specific restrictions such as the [immutable attribute](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) on Linux's ext2 filesystem and successors.

¹  <sub>Except insofar as he process running `chmod` must be able to access the file, so it must have execute permission on the directory containing the file and any other directory that it traverses to do so.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The details you want are in the manual page for the chmod() system call.  Instead of `man chmod` use `man 2 chmod`.  `man chattr` and `man 2 setxattr` will interest you as well; the file attributes that chattr/setxattr() set augment the behavior of the traditional Unix permissions set by chmod.

Comment: I'll try this when I get out of work.

Answer (score 1):

> Can users use chmod to change permissions on a file they have group access for?

Why don't you just try and see?

```
$ touch foo
$ sudo install -o root -g $(id -gn) -m660 foo bar
$ ls -la bar
-rw-rw----  1 root  staff  0 Oct 21 21:33 bar
$ chmod g-w bar
chmod: bar: Operation not permitted
$ chmod g+x bar
chmod: bar: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I have been poking at it, but this is security related and I don't want to accidentally miss an edge case.

Comment: If you're worried about an edge case, you can (at least to minimize risks) do the `chmod`, and then check the permissions on it. If you're feeling paranoid, do an `fsync` before checking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the UNIX standard, "The effective user ID of the process must match the owner of the file or the process must have appropriate privileges in order to do this."

The bit about appropriate privileges needs some explanation. On traditional systems, chmod is allowed on all files when the effective UID (on Linux the filesystem UID, but see below) of the process is 0 [i.e. root].

Linux has a system called [capabilities](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), and the `CAP_FOWNER` bit controls the ability to use `chmod` on all files.  By default, all capabilities are granted when an `execve()` call creates a root process (either by executing a setuid binary or when the real UID is 0) or when the effective UID is set to 0 (and removed when it is set to a nonzero value), and a set of capabilities including `CAP_FOWNER` are enabled when the filesystem UID is set to 0 (and disabled when it is set to a nonzero value). Read the manpage for more details.

You mentioned the sticky bit, but omitted the fact that users also may not set the setgid bit on a file when they are not in the group that is assigned to the file. The setuid or setgid bit may also be ignored in additional implementation-defined circumstances.