# Permission for group user to change permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

After I set the permission to have both groups added to different user I am still not able to change the permission for directory and files.

```
id adminOne
uid=495(adminOne) gid=492(apps) groups=492(apps),5002(shared)

id adminTwo
uid=7376(adminTwo) gid=5002(shared) groups=5002(shared),492(apps)
```

If I log in with adminOne I changed a shared folder such as `test`...

```
adminOne@UnixEB: chmod -R 777 test
chmod: changing permissions of `test': Operation not permitted

adminOne@UnixEB: ll
drwxrwx--- 7 adminTwo shared 4096 Nov 30 11:40 test
```

why I cannot change the permission when I already set the owner to both groups?

Comment: May be the folder has some extended attributes set?

Comment: what do you mean by extended attribute set?

Comment: ACLs.  Immutability.  Read-only filesystem.  There are many possibilities.

Comment: Is `SELinux` enabled? What is the output of `getenforce`?

Comment: With traditional (non-ACL) access rights, only the owner can change the permissions of a file.

Comment: @Abhik Bose when I did adminOne@UnixEB: getenforce
It says Disabled

Comment: What's happening without the `-R` option?

Comment: @Abhik Bose same problem.

Comment: @logger <https://serverfault.com/questions/126347/how-to-allow-members-of-a-group-to-change-file-permissions-on-linux> saying writing permission not equal to `chmod` permission. So one solution is change the group user as owner and the owner as group user with `sudo` right. Please update with the result.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned this in a comment above, but it's worth calling out again.  Having write permissions does not give a non-owner the right to modify the permissions of a file – only the owner (or root) can change a file's permissions.

You may be able to use ACLs to enable what you're after; see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75915/90691

Comment: That's about "Richacls" in particular, not POSIX ACL:s. It seems that Richacls was included in OpenSUSE, but [removed some years ago](http://opensuse-kernel.opensuse.narkive.com/pIjtDYia/richacl-patches-in-factoryremoved). And judging from [this post](https://lwn.net/Articles/718804/) from April 2017, it's still not in mainline Linux either

Comment: Yeah, that's why I qualified the comment with "may be able to".  I'd never heard of Richacls, I was just referencing the related discussion.